# MongoSocketOpenException when using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.0.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to build spring boot MongoDB project provided at https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/ which is using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.0.0.RELEASE,
and getting

stack trace:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:114) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket operation on non-socket (Error setting socket option)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketSetOption0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketSetOption(PlainSocketImpl.java:88) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.setOption(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:275) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.net.Socket.setTcpNoDelay(Socket.java:980) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:36) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
... 3 common frames omitted
```

When I changed spring-boot-starter-parent version to 1.5.9.RELEASE  or 1.5.10.RELEASE, the same code is working fine. So is there any problem with version 2.0.0.RELEASE when using spring data mongo.

System details:

mongod version: 3.4.13

openjdk version "1.8.0_151"

Answer (score 0):

I had to install and start mongodb first for spring-boot-starter-parent 2.0.x

assuming you are using MacOS

```
# to install mongodb
➜  ~ brew install mongodb 
# To have launchd start mongodb now and restart at login
➜  ~ brew services start mongodb
```

after that everything worked as expected:

```
2018-04-05 22:13:43.189  INFO 26777 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2018-04-05 22:13:43.229  INFO 26777 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:1}] to localhost:27017
2018-04-05 22:13:43.234  INFO 26777 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 3]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=3049505}
2018-04-05 22:13:43.352  INFO 26777 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2018-04-05 22:13:43.469  INFO 26777 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:2}] to localhost:27017
2018-04-05 22:13:43.471  INFO 26777 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 3]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=1552605}
```